# Python `for` does not iterate over enumerate object

Tags: python, loops, iteration, python-3.4, enumerable

Why does this not iterate?

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

x = []
y = [[] for n in range(0, 1)]
linedata = ["0","1","2"]
x.append( linedata[0] )

d = linedata[1:] 
logging.debug( "d: {}".format(d) )
e = enumerate(d)
logging.debug( list(e) )
for k, v in e:
  logging.debug( "k:{} v:{}".format( k, v ) )
  y[int(k)].append( v )
  #for d in [(0,1)]:
  #logging.debug( "k:{} v:{}".format( d[0], d[1] ) )
  #y[d[0]].append( d[1] )

logging.debug( x )
logging.debug( y )
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:root:d: ['1', '2']
DEBUG:root:[(0, '1'), (1, '2')]
DEBUG:root:['0']
DEBUG:root:[[]]
```

Docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Run online: http://goo.gl/75yuAd

Comment: Try: for k, v in enumerate(d):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any iterator is "one-shot" in sense that, when it is fully executed, it becomes empty and can't be used anymore. When you called `logging.debug( list(e) )`, you have used it in the list() function and so exhausted it. So, the following attempt to use it in `for` cycle gives nothing.

With modified code when enumerate() is called again after this debug, the script behavior gets changed - it raises IndexError on `y[int(k)].append( v )`; I won't fix this for you but this is enough sign that cycle body begins being executed.

Comment: _"Any iterator is "one-shot" in sense that, when it is fully executed, it becomes empty and can't be used anymore"_ : this is not true. You can easily write an infinite iterator, and there are a couple ones in `itertools`, like `count()`, `cycle()` and `repeat()`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That doesn't invalidate the statement. Those are examples of iterators which don't become exhausted.

Comment: @Marcin: half-empty glass vs half-full glass... But Python newcomers should know that not all iterators are finite.

Answer (score 3):

Because `enumerate` returns an iterator:

```
>>> e = enumerate(range(4))
>>> list(e)
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> list(e)
[]
```

Once the end is reached, `e.next()` raises a `StopIteration` exception:

```
>>> e.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Thus you cannot iterate twice over `e`. You will have to recreate the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

this line :

```
logging.debug( list(e) )
```

consumes the iterator, so when you get here:

```
for k, v in e:
   # ...
```

`e` is already exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
e = list(enumerate(d))
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information along with your answer?